# using the Document in external JS file not working

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to code a game in JS. I created a html file with a canvas, a main.js file where i will write the code. Now i want to get the context of the canvas so I can draw on it.

The problem is, when I create a variable "canvas" in main.js, and give it the value : document.getElementById('gameScreen'), and print it in the console to see if it works, I just don't get anything. No error, no message, the console stays empty. Furthermore, when I try to get the context of the canvas, my editor (visual studio code, portable version) doesn't recognise the getContext method.

First I thought my code was wrong, so I tried writing it into a  tag. And the code worked. So my javascript code only works when in the html file. 
I have had this problem for a long time, but I only had short scripts, so there wasn't any problem in including it in a  tag. But now, coding a game in a single file is impossible as it gets really messy really fast. I tried running the html file in other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, internet Explorer) but I always get the same result.

Here is the html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game - Platformer</title>
        <script src="/js_source/main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/platformer.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="gameScreen"></canvas>
    </body>

</html>
```

And here the JS file:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
console.log(ctx);
```

I think it is a linking problem, is there something specific to write in the JS file to access the document? Obviously the code isn't executed; I suppose if the variable ctx doesn't contain anything the console should tell it, right?

Comment: By default JavaScript code executes synchronously as the document is being built. So when it runs your `script` tag in the `head`, it hasn't created the `canvas` yet. Easiest solution: try moving your `script` tag to the bottom of the `body` tag, after the `canvas`.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Just tried it but unfortunately doesn't work yet. I can't find anybody else who has had the same problem,

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that you said "I tried running the html file in other browsers..." Does that mean you are directly accessing the file from your drive using something like `file:///path/to/file.html`? If so you are probably also having a problem because of your absolute src path for the script. Try removing the leading slash: `src="js_source/main.js"`. I've tried your exact code both using my localhost web server and also accessing via `file:///...` as above, and if I use a relative `src` and move the script tag to the bottom of the `body` it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You have not linked the external js files with your HTML file, use

```
<script src="/js_source/main.js"></script>
```

, but the main problem is you need to use it in the body, not the head so that it should function.

you can check the following resources for more explanations.
https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-add-javascript-to-html
different ways to add a js file to an HTML document